# Routing to a different route

Tags: angular, routes

I am using Router link in my Angular 4 app and try routing to the following

```
[routerLink]="['/CostofOwnership/ownership-result', cons.name]
```

but instead this is the URL that it goes to

http://localhost:4200/?changeName=Cost+of+a+new+valve&default=7000&changeName=Cost+of+a+new+actuator+assembly&default=3000&changeName=Cost+to+repair+the+valve+%28Repair+kit+and+labour%29&default=1800&changeName=Cost+to+remove+and+re-install+the+valve&default=5000&changeName=Cost+to+generate+a+purchase+order&default=350&changeName=Cost+to+decontaminate+a+valve+that+has+been+in+service&default=450&changeName=Cost+of+packaging+and+shipping+the+valve&default=900&changeName=Cost+to+test+a+new%2Frepaired+valve+before+it+is+installed&default=65&changeName=Cost+of+storage+for+spare+valves%2Frepair+kits&default=40&changeName=Cost+to+insulate+the+valve&default=450&changeName=Cost+of+an+unscheduled+shutdown&default=0#/CostofOwnership/ownership-result/Default

Why is it adding the huge string in the beginning?

Edit:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    data: {
      title: 'ownership-cost'
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: 'ownership-result-compare',
        component: OwnershipResultCompareComponent,
        data: {
          title: 'Ownership-Form'
        }
      },
      {
        path: 'ownership-form/:typeOf',
        component: OwnershipFormComponent,
        data: {
          title: 'Ownership-Form'
        }
      },
      {
        path: 'ownership-form-admin/:uid/:typeOf',
        component: OwnershipAdminComponent,
        data: {
          title: 'Ownership-Form-Admin'
        }
      },
      {
        path: 'ownership-result/:typeOf',
        component: OwnershipResultComponent,
        data: {
          title: 'Ownership-Result'
        }
      },
      {
        path: 'ownership-result-admin/:uid/:typeOf',
        component: OwnershipResultAdminComponent,
        data: {
          title: 'Ownership-Result-Admin'
        }
      },
      {
        path: 'ownership-question',
        component: OwnershipQuestionComponent,
        data: {
          title: 'Ownership-Question'
        }
      },
      {
        path: 'ownership-inform',
        component: OwnershipInformComponent,
        data: {
          title: 'Ownership-Information'
        }
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you paste the routes file as well(need to see the routes).

Comment: added the routes from the routing file

Comment: assuming that these routes are under the feature module - CostofOwnership, and you have route like - /CostofOwnership/***. Can you try to print the value of cons.name ( {{cons.name}} ) in the html template. make sure you are getting the right value.

Comment: it appears that `'/CostofOwnership/ownership-result'` is not a valid url if that is your whole route config. You can turn on debug mode by adding `{enableTracing: true}` to your router module setup like this. `RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {enableTracing:true}),` that will help debug router errors.

Comment: @Jay I've checked that it's getting the right value. It works in Chrome as it goes to /CostofOwnership/ownership-result, but I'm not sure why when I try it in Safari it goes to the long url first and then the correct one

Comment: Thats odd. I will also checkout related questions, if find will add the link here.